# Mysql takes more time in sending data

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal-views, cpu-usage

I have this particular query which takes long time to execute, other queries on the same tables execute very fast. Querycache is enabled in mysql but still the below query takes more than 80 seconds everytime and CPU crosses 100% utilization.

I cannot modify the query because it is generated by Drupal. Is there anything else I can do to improve performance?

The **query** is:

```sql
select count(*) 
from (
    SELECT slk.key_id AS key_id 
    FROM slk slk  
        LEFT JOIN users users ON    slk.uid = users.uid 
        LEFT JOIN node node_users ON users.uid = node_users.uid 
            AND   node_users.type = 'profile'
) count_alias;
```

Below is the **profile** information:

```
+--------------------------------+-----------+
| Status                         | Duration  |
+--------------------------------+-----------+
| starting                       |  0.000029 | 
| checking query cache for query |  0.000093 | 
| Opening tables                 |  0.000210 | 
| System lock                    |  0.000007 | 
| Table lock                     |  0.000075 | 
| optimizing                     |  0.000008 | 
| statistics                     |  0.000113 | 
| preparing                      |  0.000027 | 
| executing                      |  0.000004 | 
| Sending data                   | 66.086903 | 
| init                           |  0.000027 | 
| optimizing                     |  0.000009 | 
| executing                      |  0.000018 | 
| end                            |  0.000003 | 
| query end                      |  0.000004 | 
| freeing items                  |  0.000049 | 
| storing result in query cache  |  0.000116 | 
| removing tmp table             |  0.033162 | 
| closing tables                 |  0.000106 | 
| logging slow query             |  0.000003 | 
| logging slow query             |  0.000085 | 
| cleaning up                    |  0.000007 | 
+--------------------------------+-----------+
```

**explain** on the query gives:

```
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys         | key     | key_len | ref             | rows  | Extra                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | NULL       | NULL   | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL    | NULL            |  NULL | Select tables optimized away | 
|  2 | DERIVED     | slk        | ALL    | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL    | NULL            | 55862 |                              | 
|  2 | DERIVED     | users      | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY | 4       | gscom.slk.uid   |     1 | Using index                  | 
|  2 | DERIVED     | node_users | ref    | node_type,uid,idx_ctp | uid     | 4       | gscom.users.uid |     3 |                              |
```

`idx_ctp` is an index on (`uid`, `type`).

The query cache is working and below are the stats.

`show variables like '%query_cache%';`:

```
| Variable_name                | Value    |
| have_query_cache             | YES      | 
| query_cache_limit            | 2097152  | 
| query_cache_min_res_unit     | 4096     | 
| query_cache_size             | 52428800 | 
| query_cache_type             | ON       | 
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF      |
```

`mysql> show status like '%Qcache%';`:

```
| Variable_name           | Value    |
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 1255     | 
| Qcache_free_memory      | 22902848 | 
| Qcache_hits             | 1484908  | 
| Qcache_inserts          | 1036344  | 
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 95086    | 
| Qcache_not_cached       | 3975     | 
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 14271    | 
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 30117    |
```

Comment: Why don't you just rewrite that query into something more meaningful? If you want to see which steps are taking time, use `SET PROFILING = 1; SELECT...; SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1; SET PROFILING = 0;`.

Comment: sending data takes most of the time, i have tuned mysql giving more to querycache but still this query is not getting cached and takes 80 seconds everytime, rest of the functionalities in my drupal site does not work in the mean time

Comment: Can a slk have many users? And can a user have many nodes of type 'profile'? In other words, are those joins really necesary? Also, try writting count(1) instead of count(*).

Comment: @Pavan: What are the datatypes of the columns (used by the query)?

Answer (score 2):

You need indexes on:

- table `slk`:  `(uid)`
- table `node_users`: `(type, uid)`

---

The query can be rewritten without subquery, as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM slk 
    LEFT JOIN users 
        ON slk.uid = users.uid 
    LEFT JOIN node node_users 
        ON  users.uid = node_users.uid 
        AND node_users.type = 'profile'
```

---

And I'm really not sure why you use `LEFT JOIN`. You can probably use `INNER JOIN` and have the same result. Or just use the simple:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM slk
```

Comment: sorry for not mentioning it more clearly, i already have those indexes which are reflected in the explain information.

Comment: You say you have an index on `(uid, type)`. I mean an index on `(type, uid)`. The order matters.

Comment: This query is automatically generated by drupal[link](drupal.org) views, so there is little handle with me to modify the query. The same type of join is used other queries as well but they gets executed very fast(few ms to 1 sec). Why is this query is not cached in mysql?

Comment: sure, i will add the index on (type, uid) and check the result. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: And check that you do have an index on `slk(uid)`.

Comment: @ypercube In this case order does not matter because he is using both fields to filter. If he was using only "type" then it would matter. Also, if the index where to be created, then it would not need the field uid (for the same reason: if both fields where used to filter, then the query use the original index). Second also: if there are not many different types, then the index would be almost useless.

Comment: +1 Nice job breaking down the query into just the necessary part. Too bad the OP can't fix it.

Comment: adding the index on (type, uid) made the query to use the index. Thanks @ypercude. I could not understand how it is different from the other index(uid, type), i will read further to know more about it. Few things i could not resolve yet are 1. Why query caching is not helping in this case, 2. When i add more joins, the index is no more used and the query takes long time, how does the usage of index changes when extra joins are added to the query

Comment: Do you also show other columns in the Select list or you have extra conditions in the Where clause, when you do that (extra joins)?

Comment: sorry for my inactiveness here as i'm new to posting on stackoverflow and i have no tracking enabled. @ypercube to get few other other fields also, i add extra joins on the node table (around 4 different joins on node table itself) . Following your hint on adding indexes, i have added a lot of indexes but could not improve because of the way my query is framed. MySQL could not create indexes and takes long time for the count query. After reading more about the MySQL working, i think sometimes query rewrite is the only option.

Comment: unfortunately in my scenario Drupal CMS is creating the query and i have no handle to alter it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Pavan: Have you added the suggested indexes? Drupal does not do that automatically, does it?

Comment: I have added the indexes from the mysql client.

Answer (score 2):

This is a poor query. It selects all 55862 rows from the `slk` table and joins all 55862 rows to two other tables.

JOINs on large result sets are performance killers because MySQL must, at best, perform a seek for each row in the master table to the corresponding rows in the detail table. If there are too many rows, MySQL will decide it's just faster to scan the entire detail table rather than perform so many seeks.

Creating a multi-column index on `node_users: (uid, type)`, as ypercube suggested, will help the second join (to the node_users) table.

Ideally, if this query were using INNER JOINs instead of LEFT OUTER JOINs, we could optimize the query by allowing MySQL to traverse it backwards, starting with the `AND node_users.type = 'profile'` and giving it the index that ypercube suggested, in the order he suggested. However, since they are left joins, MySQL will still want to get all rows in the `slk` table, and will start from there.

The only additional thing you can do to improve the performance of this query without modifying it is to avoid hitting the table data by using covering indexes.

This will use a lot more memory, but hopefully, it will be faster because it can read all the values from the indexes (in memory) rather than hitting the disk. This implies that you have enough RAM to support having all of the indexes in memory and you've configured MySQL to use it.

You already have a covering index on `users` (see `Using index` in the EXPLAIN result). You want all three lines of the DERIVED query to say `Using index` in the Extra column.

Create the additional following covering index:

```
slk: (key_id, uid)
```

This one was already mentioned above, but I'm including it here again so you don't forget it:

```
node_users: (uid, type)
```

You won't get breakthrough performance here because you're still having to do all of the JOINs, but you will get some improvement. Let us know how much faster it is. I'm guessing about twice as fast.